# mongodb GEO2D Index - kilometers?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I have a geospatial index in my database.  [MongoDB's documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) says that the $near operator takes an argument in meters to find matches.  For example:

```
db.data.find({'coordinates': SON([('$near', [20.450550042732765, 80.52327036857605]), ('$maxDistance', 100)])}).count()
```

should return matches within 100 meters of that location.  But too many are returned, about 3,000.  When I rewrite the query as

```
db.data.find({'coordinates': SON([('$near', [20.450550042732765, 80.52327036857605]), ('$maxDistance', 1)])}).count()
```

I receive 364 results.  I do not think my database has 364 matches within a 1 meter radius of the point I query.  Finally, if I query

```
db.data.find({'coordinates': SON([('$near', [20.450550042732765, 80.52327036857605]), ('$maxDistance', .1)])}).count()
```

I receive 330 matches.  There are definitely not 330 results within 10 centimeters of that point.

I think mongodb interprets distance as kilometers, not meters.  Can anyone confirm or explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the legacy `2d` index, and it looks like that's what you're doing, then `$maxDistance` is in radians, as per the documentation you linked to.